# How to find a list of editable attributes in a class - Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When creating a product I can use the following via the API:

```
$newProductData = array(
                'name'              => (string)$stockItem->STOCK_DESC,
                'websites'          => array(1,2), // array(1,2,3,...)
                'short_description' => (string)$stockItem->STOCK_DESC,
                'description'       => (string)$stockItem->LONG_DESC,
                'status'            => 1,
                'weight'            => $stockItem->WEIGHT,
                'tax_class_id'      => 1,
                'categories'        => array(3108),
                'price'             => $stockItem->SELL_PRICE
            );

            $my_set_id = 9;  // Use whatever set_id you want here
            $type = 'simple';

            $mc = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api();
            $mc->create($type, $my_set_id, $stockItem->STOCK_CODE, $newProductData);
```

When I look into the `$mc->create` call I see that it does this:

```
foreach ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getEditableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
}
```

which indicates there is a list of attributes which can be edited against an object.

How do I find these? Is there a specific place this information is found?

**Edit**: I just did:

```
Mage::log($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getEditableAttributes($product));
```

and had a look at the results. It seems all the editable attributes are there which can be found under `[attribute_code] =>` but I would still like a better method of knowing where to look to get this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will depend entirely on the attribute set of the product you're trying to edit, and the configuration of each individual attribute.  There's no place in the UI that will list these attributes out for you.  Your best bet is to run some custom code for your product

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
foreach ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getEditableAttributes($product) as $code=>$attribute)    
{
    var_dump($code); 
}
```

Here's how to track this information down. If you jump to the `getEditableAttributes` method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Abstract.php
public function getEditableAttributes($product = null)
{
    $cacheKey = '_cache_editable_attributes';
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($cacheKey)) {
        $editableAttributes = array();
        foreach ($this->getSetAttributes($product) as $attributeCode => $attribute) {
            if (!is_array($attribute->getApplyTo())
                || count($attribute->getApplyTo())==0
                || in_array($this->getProduct($product)->getTypeId(), $attribute->getApplyTo())) {
                $editableAttributes[$attributeCode] = $attribute;
            }
        }
        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($cacheKey, $editableAttributes);
    }
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($cacheKey);
}
```

You can see that this method gets a list of all the attributes set on a particular product.(i.e. All the attributes that are a member of the product's attribute set).  Once it has this list, it goes through each and checks if its `apply_to` property matches the type id of the current product.

The Apply To attribute is set at

```
Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes -> [Pick Attribute]
```

[image]

This form field updates the database table `catalog_eav_attribute`.  If you run the following query you can see examples of this value as is stored

```
select attribute_id, apply_to from catalog_eav_attribute where apply_to is NOT NULL;
75  simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable
76  simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable
77  simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable
78  simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable
79  virtual,downloadable
```

So, get your product's attribute set.  Get a list of attributes in that set.  Compare the value of the attribute's `apply_to` field vs. the value of your product's `type_id`.  That will let you build a list of these attributes.

Comment: Splendid, many thanks Alan. Magento is a steeper learning curve than I imagined it would be when I started this endeavor :)